# Requests are sent twice, Angular 4

Tags: angular

Every HTTP request is sent twice after a request that I called in `ngOnInit()`.

[image]

Comment: Don't attach the image to the question, just copy paste the code to question that helps readers to follow up.

Comment: Maybe could be a CORS related issue, see my answer here maybe it can clarify https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034547/2860519

Answer (score 0):

Because you're sendgin both an OPTIONS and GET requests.

[See more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)