# Two calls triggering on click of post request using HttpClient

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

After adding headers inside code duplicate call is happening. find the image to see the call happening twice.

**auth-interceptor.ts**

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const clonedRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('X-CustomAuthHeader', 'some-auth-token')
    });

    console.log("new headers", clonedRequest.headers.keys());

    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
}
```

}

[Please fine calls log image here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY8vM.jpg)

[call log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7RDR.jpg)

[call log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLkAD.jpg)

Comment: Show us more logs. This is probably because the first call is just method OPTIONS. this is normal. Your browser checking request URL before sending real request

Comment: @WitoldTkaczyk: i have added two call log images .. please find those from above. and comment why its happening

Comment: yup, my answer is right

Comment: but this duplicate call is not happening if am not adding headers..this occurs only after adding headers

Comment: because that is how corse works. Read this http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I know the duplicate says angularjs but the problem is the same and @WitoldTkaczyk is right. I can re-open it if you want.

Comment: thank you @WitoldTkaczyk

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @WitoldTkaczyk options call is not triggering if call is from same domain. why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of request is called **Preflighted requests** that corresponds to a negotiation between the caller and the Web application based on HTTP headers.

It consists of two phases:

1. The browser executes an **OPTIONS request** with the same URL as the target request to check that it has the rights to execute the request. This **OPTIONS request** returns headers that identify what is possible to do for the URL.
2. If rights match, the browser executes the request.

[image]

[Reference here](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/).

Comment: How does your answer differ from mine?

Comment: Your answer is correct, i answered trying to add value with a little bit of information and the image is very illustrative :D

Answer (score 0):

The first call is triggered by [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> It sends first an OPTION request to check if the domain, from which the request is sent, is the same as the one from the server.
>
> Notice that if you add authentication to the request using the Authentication header, simple requests automatically become preflighted ones.

See also helpful [article](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/) for more information.